# Change css on a single element when clicked and revert css on other elements

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, navigation

I have a mobile navigation that has 4 dropdown elements. Onclick of a single element i would like to change element css and open a dropdown menu, and if other elements are open to close them and revert css.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="mobileNavBar">
  <div class="svgikonica" id="svgStan">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p>
    Stanovništvo
  </p>
</div>
<div class="podlinkovi">
  <a href="#">Mobile Express racun</a>
  <a href="#">Mobile Standard racun</a>
  <a href="#">Krediti</a>
</div>

<div class="mobileNavBar">
  <div class="svgikonica">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p>
    Privreda
  </p>
</div>
<div class="podlinkovi">
  <a href="#">Platni promet</a>
</div>

<div class="mobileNavBar">
  <div class="svgikonica">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    </svg>

  </div>
  <p>
    O Nama
  </p>
</div>
<div class="podlinkovi">
  <a href="#">Novosti</a>
</div>

<div class="mobileNavBar">
  <div class="svgikonica">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    </svg>

  </div>
  <p>
    Info centar
  </p>
</div>
<div class="podlinkovi">
  <a href="#">Kontakt centar</a>
  <a href="#">Bankomati</a>
  <a href="#">Poslovnice</a>
  <a href="#">Kursna lista</a>
  <a href="#">Medija centar</a>
</div>'
```

On the click of each .mobileNavBar css needs to change and .podlinkovi needs to open.

This is the jquery of what needs to happen

```
    $('.mobileNavBar').click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
    $('.podlinkovi').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.mobileNavBar p').css({float: 'right', 'color' : '#fff',  'padding-left' : '0px'}, 500);
    $('.svgikonica svg').css({stroke: '#fff'}, 500);
    } else {
    $('.podlinkovi').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.mobileNavBar p').css({float: 'left', 'color' : '#BF3B50', 'padding-left' : '20px'}, 500);
    $('.svgikonica svg').css({stroke: '#BF3B50'}, 500);
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
    });
```

i need to add to this function that on click only one .mobileNavBar changes class styles and only the one .podlinkovi opens and all other close

and here is the CSS

```
  .mobileNavBar{
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.podlinkovi{
display: none;
}
.svgikonica {
float: left;
}
.svgikonica svg {
stroke: white;
height:50px;
padding:5px;
}
.mobileNavBar p{
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}
.podlinkovi a{
width: 100%;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
color: black;
float: left;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 5px 0;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 5px;
```

Comment: Don't directly style the elements. Use a class on the selected one, then when another is selected remove the class from any previously-selected one.

Comment: Where is your CSS?